# substitute list of equations into expression

Tags: substitution, maxima

In the following toy problem I'd like to evaluate `j(fxxx)` but with with the actual numbers for `a,b,c` that `solve` produces, is there a way to do that? According to the docs there is [`subst`](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/maxima_6.html#subst) but it takes three arguments (variables to be substituted, the values, and the expression).

```
display2d:false;
i(f) := integrate(f(x),x,0,1);
j(f) := a*f(0)+b*f(1/2)+c*f(1);
f1(x) := 1;
fx(x) := x;
fxx(x) := x^2;
fxxx(x) := x^3;
print(solve([i(f1) = j(f1), i(fx) = j(fx), i(fxx) = j(fxx)],[a,b,c]));
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY5BCoMwEEX3niLLTB2osTuDJxELoyYloq0YKdPTp0kJdvXf43@YWYndSiFMzm8LfeqpsbR4owsnLYimFe55mMdOh5FWMiBjhQp0MeeaLlZWUA4x1LWGckwQe6viOg1UZM7MiU@51z/9@00X2x7vSf9a3kZ28QUFohVzShRROStnPZ2hx45wwLEH0CF8AQ)

Answer (score 2):

Actually I should have finished reading the docs, we can actually still use `subst`:

```
i(f) := integrate(f(x),x,0,1);
j(f) := a*f(0)+b*f(1/2)+c*f(1);
f1(x) := 1;
fx(x) := x;
fxx(x) := x^2;
fxxx(x) := x^3;
jj(g) := subst(solve([i(f1) = j(f1), i(fx) = j(fx), i(fxx) = j(fxx)],[a,b,c]),j(g));
print(jj(g));
print(jj(fxxx)-i(fxxx));
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY/RDoIwDEXf/Yo9tlIjwzcJX0IwGYSRLaIE0PTvZ4cLJj7de9Lm9nY07EYTggOL6lop91j7YTZrDxYYiSknjeXBp7E5Wsgxa0X0ucCsi0bmVst2XNDiOXmOfodbseGPLxLrYdhoebXLCsvz/u6hli4aVaV8VFKCnJAT7szYUG2opa5BimHSZZrlCfD/FG/jyX0VyxA@)